# how to make sure inner dependency method was called in service

Tags: vitest

I have a project created with Vite and Vitest for unit testing. I have problems with creating properly mocks/spies.

I have a service which have an inner dependency

```
    const useMainService = () => {
          const modals = useModals();
        
          function makeCalculationAndShowModal() {
            // if ...
        
            modals.show();
        
            return true;
          }
        
          return {
            makeCalculationAndShowModal,
          };
        };

const useModals = () => {
  function show() {
    console.log('modal showed');
  }

  return {
    show,
  };
};
```

I created a bunch of unit tests:

```
describe('useMainService', () => {
  it('check result', () => {
    // this works
    const result = useMainService().makeCalculationAndShowModal();

    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('spy test', () => {
    // this works
    const consoleMock = vi.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => {});

    useMainService().makeCalculationAndShowModal();

    expect(consoleMock).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    expect(consoleMock).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('modal showed');
  });

  it('mock test', async () => {
    const consoleMock = vi.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation(() => {});
    const useModals = await import('../src/useModals');

    useModals.default = vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        show: vi.fn(() => {
          debugger;
          console.log(`show modal from mock`);
        }),
      };
    });

    useMainService().makeCalculationAndShowModal();

    // this work
    expect(consoleMock).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    expect(consoleMock).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('show modal from mock');

    // this doesn't work
    expect(useModals.default().show).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
  });
});
```

My problem is related to last test. In this specific case I can spy on the global console object and it seems to work properly. But in my real code, I have no global object to relay on, so I need to have the possibility to check, if that mock function was even called. The way I did it in the last test doesn't work. How can I fix it? Or maybe should I use a spy too? But don't know how to write it to make it work.

A working project is available here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-toomcq?file=test%2FuseMainService.test.ts